# Does the CGWH-fication change the (weak) homotopy type?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $Top$, $CG$, $WH$, $CGWH$ be the categories of topological spaces, compactly generated spaces, weak Hausdorff spaces and compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces.

There is the CG-ification $X_{CG}$ of a space $X$ and the WH-ification $X_{WH}$ of a compactly generated space $X$. These provide adjoint pairs between $Top$ and $CG$ and also between $CG$ and $CGWH$. Combined, they give me the CGWH-fication $(X_{CG})_{WH}=X_{CGWH}$ of a space $X$. The latter one is the one used implicitly in most of today's algebraic topology.

**I'm interested in the question which of these constructions can change the (weak) homotopy type and which of them preserves it.** It seems to me that at least in many cases, the weak homotopy type must be preserved. I really don't want to have $\Omega X$ to have a different homotopy type depending on whether I used the compactly generated topology on the mapping space or not.

Comment: Are you sure that the weakHausdorffication works for every space? I know that it can be applied to a $k$-space $X$, where it is $X/R$ with $R$ being the smallest closed equivalence relation in the $k$-product $X\times X$. This yields a functor $CG\to CGWH$.

Comment: You are right. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 11):

It is very easy to see that CG-ification preserves weak homotopy type: it is a right adjoint, so for any CG space $K$, the maps $K\to X_{CG}$ are the same as the maps $K\to X$.  Letting $K$ be $S^n$ and $S^n\times I$ immediately gives that the map $X_{CG}\to X$ is a weak equivalence.

However, WH-ification does not preserve weak homotopy type.  For instance, if $X$ is a space with finitely many points, then $X$ is CG, and $X_{WH}$ will always be discrete (since it is a finite $T_1$ space).  However, finite spaces can have the weak homotopy type of any finite CW-complex!  So WH-ification can really destroy a lot of homotopy-theoretic information when applied to arbitrary spaces.  This rarely is a cause for concern though.  For instance, you mentioned being worried about the topology on loopspaces, but the CG-ification of the loopspace of a CGWH space is automatically already WH (see Proposition 2.24 of [this excellent paper](http://dedekind.mit.edu/~mbehrens/18.906/cgwh.pdf), for instance).

Comment: "However, finite spaces can have the weak homotopy type of any finite CW-complex!" This is impressive. Do you have a reference for this fact?

Comment: @Klaus: It's a theorem of McCord; [here's the original reference](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077376525).  One version of the statement is as follows.  Let $X$ be a simplicial complex, and let $Y$ be the quotient of $X$ obtained by collapsing the interior of each simplex of $X$ to a point.  Then the quotient map $X\to Y$ is a weak equivalence.  When $X$ is a finite simplicial complex, of course, this $Y$ is a finite space.